# Does QGIS offer the possibility to identify overlapping features in a single WMS layer?

Tags: qgis, wms, identify

I work in QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa and use the 'Identify feature' tool to get the feature info of building polygons found in a single layer of a WMS.
Some of these building polygons overlap.

When I select the 'building' layer and click on the intersecting part of these overlapping polygons, I expect QGIS to return multiple objects with their respective details (as I'm used to see in ArcMap). However, the 'Identify Results' window only shows one of the polygons at this location.

Does QGIS offer the possibility to identify overlapping features in a single layer? I checked the documentation but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Does this only occur with WMS layers? I don't have a WMS layer to test but this should be a standard feature of the tool.

Comment: @Joseph I did a test with overlapping objects in a shapefile. QGIS returned multiple objects, as expected. So yes, this seems to be a WMS specific problem.

Comment: Check the feature count setting in the WMS connection settings. The default in QGIS is 10. If you have this value it may be that the WMS server really returns info from one feature only.

Answer (score 2):

Before adding the WMS to the project again, I increased the value of 'Feature Limit for GetFeatureInfo' from 10 to 50 in the WMS connection settings. This solved the problem. The 'identify feature' tool now returns the details of overlapping features in a single WMS layer. Thanks @user30184!

Answer (score 1):

In OpenLayers or Leaflet, you can pass the `FEATURE_COUNT` parameter to QGIS Server. In 2.14 the default value is 1, so it gets only the feature on the top. Putting it to > 1 gets more features.